# «На самом деле». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**На самом же деле(,) его уступчивость имеет разумные пределы.**
Нужна ли запятая после "на самом деле"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"На самом деле" - это вводное слово (сочетание). Значит, запятая нужна.

Answer (score 11):

Запятая здесь **не нужна**, так как выражение "на самом деле" здесь является членом предложения - обстоятельством и употребляется в значении "действительно", "в действительности".

Сочетание **в самом деле** *в значении «действительно»* **не является вводным**: ***Коньяк в самом деле оказался хорошим (Ч.); Он и в самом деле интересовался философией (Кар.)***.

***Но если*** это сочетание служит ***для выражения недоумения, возмущения, негодования*** и т. п., то ***оно становится вводным и обособляется***; ср.: Вы **в самом деле** здесь ни при чём? **(«действительно»**). — Что он, **в самом деле**, строит из себя умника?(http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Обособление наречного выражения "на самом же деле" зависит **от контекста.**

Я приведу пример из **художественной** литературы, где это сочетание **обособляется.**

**Василий Аксенов**. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)

*Аптека находилась в большом сером здании. Когда стоишь на тротуаре и смотришь вверх на эти восемь этажей, **кАжется**, что находишься в огромном городе. **На сАмом же деле, здание это было единственным в своем роде.***

Здесь обособление связано с **противопоставлением:** кажется так, а в действительности иначе.  Именно поэтому автор **обособил** речевой оборот, чтобы это противопоставление **подчеркнуть.** Также обратим внимание на усилительную **частицу  ЖЕ.**

2. Контекста нет, но можно **представить**, о чем там речь, например:

*Он кажется мягким, уступчивым человеком. **На самом же деле**, его уступчивость имеет разумные пределы.*

Comment: Получается, запятая всё же нужна?

Comment: Скорее нужна, судя по частице ЖЕ. Мы выделяем сочетание  с ЖЕ логическим ударением. Всегда нужно учитывать смысл сообщения, а отвечающие усилительную частицу не учитывают, как будто ее и нет.