# Нужна ли запятая? Всегда ли отделяется (обособляется) "на самом деле"?

Tags: запятые

Теперь вы знаете о произошедшем. Но сможем ли мы понять, кто же такой Чонгук (,) на самом деле?

Comment: Без понятия, может [это](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) поможет

Comment: Это не поможет, ибо разница существенная.

Answer (score 1):

Теперь вы знаете о произошедшем. Но сможем ли мы понять, кто же такой Чонгук **на самом деле?**

Это наречное выражение со значением "действительно, фактически" в роли обстоятельства. Вводным словом не является и не обособляется.

Паузы нет,  наречие выделено логическим ударением.

Сравнить: **На самом деле (действительно), разве можно было сразу понять, что он за человек?**  Это вводное слово. В данном случае оно  подтверждает ранее высказанное суждение