# Нужна ли запятая? "На самом деле, в любви есть условия присущие бизнес сделкам"

Tags: пунктуация

Перед словом "присущие". И если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал так:

> На самом деле в любви есть условия, присущие бизнес-сделкам.

*Присущие бизнес-сделкам* — причастный оборот, поэтому его ***надо*** обособить. Выражение *на самом деле* здесь член предложения (смотрите [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)), поэтому запятая после него у Вас лишняя. *Бизнес-сделка* пишется через дефис.