# Придаточное или составное сказуемое? "Где" в начале - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться!

> Где находится золотая середина тоже никто не уточнял, потому что, на самом деле, она для всех разная.

Нужна ли запятая после слова "середина"? 
Кажется, что по всем правилам она нужна, но что-то внутри очень протестует и ищет причину не ставить ее. Тире в качестве компромисса тоже не хочется ставить, чтобы не разбивать предложение ритмически.

Answer (score 2):

Как бы Вам ни не хотелось ставить запятую, а она всё же нужна. Не важно, сначала идёт придаточное или потом — запятой отделить его надо. А вот *"на самом деле"* обособлять как раз не надо, так как это член предложения в значении *"в действительности, фактически",* а не вводное слово. В этом [вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) есть ещё аналогичный пример.

> Где находится золотая середина, тоже никто не уточнял, потому что на самом деле она для всех разная.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Про "на самом деле" думала тоже, но поскольку это предложение из авторской статьи, и было автором обособлено так, то все же считаю это вводным оборотом. Так как тут автор не претендует на то, что утверждает о фактах действительности - скорее, рассуждает. И стилистически и ритмически обособление больше нравится. Но я еще раз подумаю. Извечная проблема авторских текстов!

Comment: Не за что, Светлана! ;)