# Загадочное вводное слово "на самом деле"

Tags: вводные-слова

**ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

С сочетанием "на самом деле" много проблем: **вводное это слово или наречие?** Многое о нем говорится: **неустойчивое** вводное сочетание или даже **лжевводное** слово, незаконно требующее от нас обособления. Может быть, следует с ним все-таки **разобраться?)**

*Действительно* и *дело* —  исторически однокоренные слова, в чем же **противоречие** между   наречными выражениями: ***действительно*** и ***на самом деле?***

Почему эти значения часто **совпадают** (нет обособления), а иногда "на самом деле" приобретает **другой** оттенок значения и вводное слово обособляется?

И как в эту систему смысловых отношений вписывается синонимичное сочетание **"собственно говоря"**, то есть какую "собственную речь" мы имеем в виду? И именно эти вопросы интересует меня **в первую очередь.**

Неясных вопросов получилось много, но я думаю, что ответ должен и может быть **коротким,** а иначе какой в нем смысл?  Нужен **ОРИЕНТИР**, по которому можно  **быстро решить** эту задачу.

**ВОПРОС**

1. Я предлагаю решить проблему **на конкретном примере. **Если заданы разные решения, то выбор приходится объяснять в каждом случае. Трудно сказать, можно ли **обобщить** тему, хотя такие попытки делаются. Или все-таки это **можно сделать?**
2. В приведенном тексте **обособление** обозначено, но сомнения остаются. Так вводное там слово или все-таки наречие? На что **ориентироваться** при решении задачи?

   ```
   Мне стало жутко! Спасите Русь!
   Повсюду бабочки и розовые пони,
   Жизнь — это шутка, и я смеюсь.
   Хотя, НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ, юмора не понял.
   ```

https://yandex.ru/video/preview/10539990556814745517

**P. S.** Я думаю, что решение здесь **ОДНОЗНАЧНОЕ**. Так какое же?

**Материалы по теме:** [Справочник по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/na-samom-dele)  [Вопрос на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) [Учебные материалы](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/na-samom-dele.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно:**

```
  Жизнь — это шутка, и я смеюсь.

  Хотя, на самом деле, юмора не понял.
```

Можно заменить: *Хотя, **признаться**, юмора не понял.*

Чтобы понять вводное слово «на самом деле», надо очень внимательно отнестись  **к русскому языку,**  как бы заглянуть в его «первозначность».

Все мы знаем значение усилительного слова **«самый».** Тогда  в  сочетании **«на самом деле»** речь идет не о простом соответствии действительности,  а о САМОЙ правдивой  (а иногда доверительной) **оценке** такого соответствия.  Другими словам,  это **правда что ни на есть**, то есть не только обозначение истины, но и **АВТОРСКОЕ подчеркивание** ее.

А что означает синонимичное слово **«собственно говоря»**, указанное в Справочнике по пунктуации?  Это **«по самой сути говоря»,** то есть наиболее правдиво и точно, и это опять же **авторское** обозначение правильного суждения.

Таким образом, у автора есть **право подчеркнуть** правдивость сказанного (а не просто обозначить), и не стоит лишать его этого права. И если в **авторском** тексте есть обособление, то его следует считать **обоснованным**.

Вот такое это **неустойчиво вводное слово,** на самом деле.

**Материалы по теме**

1. Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации.
   Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений. Опыт словаря-справочника. М.: Изд-во СГУ, 2009. 502 с.

**НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ**, наречное выражение.

(1) **Неустойчиво вводное,** решение об обособлении
принимает **автор:** на самом деле обособляется в функции
вводного при желании говорящего **подчеркнуть правдивость**
высказывания, **доверительное отношение** к собеседнику
(= если честно), интонационно выделяется. **Не обособляется** в функции обстоятельства **образа действия** (= фактически
в действительности, по-настоящему),  интонационно не
выделяется.

Ср.: *На самом деле, (= если честно) никакой семьи
у меня не было. — На самом деле (= в действительности)
никакой семьи у меня не было.*

(2) Употребляется в функции вводного в значении
«**возмущение,** неудовольствие, протест, **порицание»** (близко по
функции **к междометию**): Пора и помириться, на самом деле.

2. **Справочник по пунктуации**

**НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ,** вводное сочетание

То же, что «**собственно говоря,** в самом деле». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2.

Что еще, на самом деле, человеку надо? А. и Б. Стругацкие, За миллиард лет до конца света.

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли **члена предложения** (в знач. «в действительности, фактически»).

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнение (по содержанию текста)**

1. Скажу несколько слов **о самой песне.** Читала я отзывы и одобрительные, и пренебрежительные, причем в последних всегда виделось **дословное понимание** сложных поэтических образов. Не любит никого, а чем тут гордиться? Считает, что у других примитивная любовь, как это неправильно!

Но мне думается, что именно такое толкование  как раз и **неправильно.** Жизнь как шутка, разве об этом впервые говорится?  Разве не  про «однообразие жизни» и свое непонимании ее цели, ее назначения писал Пушкин:

```
 Цели нет передо мною:
 Сердце пусто, празден ум,
 И томит меня тоскою
 Однозвучный жизни шум.
```

**Любовь** как хобби, как привычка — может, такую любовь не приемлет автор? Есть над чем задуматься.

2. А вот еще интересный **[ответ](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%A0%D1%8D%D0%BF%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20rap%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%C2%AB%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%C2%BB)%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC.&clid=2270457&banerid=0701004840%3ASW-c2cd38eacda5&win=532&lr=213)** о **речитативе в стиле рэп**. Меня это интересует с точки зрения интонации. Рэп (от английского rap, или «бить словом») — это чтение песни речитативом.

**Русский рэп** сокращает это определение, называя лаконично «читка». Она требует умения виртуозного владения **техникой декламации,** чтобы на такты ложился ритмический рисунок. Это тем более сложнее, чем беднее музыкальное сопровождение, ведь ритмика речитатива должна совпадать с музыкальными фразами.

[Жизнь — это космическая шутка](https://studfile.net/preview/2687452/page:21/)